# Using sprite for retina with SASS/Compass

Tags: sass, npm, gruntjs, compass-sass

I'm working with [SASS/Compass sprite libraray](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) and I'm trying to configure my sprite to work with 3 icon sizes: 1x, 1.5x and 2x (retina)

this is the import of the folders:

```
@import "icons10/*.png";
@include all-icons10-sprites;
@import "icons15/*.png";
@include all-icons15-sprites;
@import "icons20/*.png";
@include all-icons20-sprites;
```

this is a mixin I am writing to manage these sprites:

```
@mixin my-icon($name) {
   @extend .icons10-#{$name};
      @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
        @extend .icons15-#{$name};
        background-position: 100% 100%;
      }
      @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
        @extend .icons20-#{$name};
      }

      $icon-width: icons10-sprite-width($name);
      $icon-height: icons10-sprite-height($name);
      width: $icon-width;
      height: $icon-height;
}
```

I'm completely clueless on how to manage `backround-size` and `background-position` in order to make the 1.5x and the 2x library to work. My questions are:

1. is there a retina solution for this specific SASS library?
2. I can manage my manual solution if I can fetch the sprite's dimensions themselves, but I don't understand how can I fetch the dimensions of the whole sprite

Answer (score 0):

There is no such build in solution in SASS so far. But if you are willing to switch to sprite maps, there is a way to get the sprite maps size:

```
background-size: image-width(sprite-path( [your sprit emap] )) image-height(sprite-path( [your sprite map] ))
```

There is a [great piece of code](https://github.com/Gaya/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass/blob/master/src/_retina-sprites.scss) from Gaya Kessler on retina sprites for compass you should check out: [Retina Sprites for Compass](https://github.com/Gaya/Retina-Sprites-for-Compass).
Adding your third icon size shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
https://gist.github.com/alanhogan/2878758

if `sprite-url` not work, you can try `sprite-file`